# Modifying UIImageView as subviews in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a scroll view to which UIImageViews were added programmatically.

I want to loop through each ImageView and adjust their frame when the device is rotated.

I've tried this but get the error "Cannot assign to 'frame' in 'view'"

```
func rotated(){

    self.imageScrollView.layoutIfNeeded()
    var iCount:CGFloat = 0
    var viewFrame = self.imageScrollView.frame
    var viewHeight = viewFrame.height
    var subviews:NSArray = self.imageScrollView.subviews
    for view in subviews{
        if let imageView = view as? UIImageView{
            var frame = CGRectMake(0, iCount * viewHeight, self.imageScrollView.frame.width, self.imageScrollView.frame.height)
            ++iCount
            view.frame = frame
        }

    }

}
```

adding the images

```
    for image in self.gallery{
            var pImageView = UIImageView()
            pImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
            var frame = CGRectMake(0, iCount * viewHeight, self.imageScrollView.frame.width, self.imageScrollView.frame.height)
            ++iCount
            pImageView.frame = frame
            let file = image["pImage"] as? PFFile
            file?.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{(data: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                var tempData = data as! NSData
                pImageView.image = UIImage(data: tempData)
                self.imageScrollView.addSubview(pImageView)
            }
        }
```

I seems that view is assigned AnyObject and cannot be cast to UIImageView which it actually is.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why are you assuming that all of the scroll view's subviews are the UIImageViews you added? That is a bad assumption. UIScrollView may have its own subviews, or if it doesn't now, may have some added at any time in the future. You need to keep an array of your pImageViews and loop through that instead of self.imageScrollView.subviews.

Comment: So are you saying that a UIScrollView may contain many different types of views that's why it can only return AnyObject? Would it be possible for you to give me an example of using an array?

Comment: You can check the class type before attempting to manipulate it

Comment: How would you do that? I tried checking to see if they were UIImageViews but they're not. Strange thing is, if I println view it shows the collection as <UIImageView> it's got me very confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the problem you are seeing is that you are using **let** which makes your imageView variable immutable. That is why you cannot change its frame.

The comment I made was not meant to address the cause of your particular problem, but to point out a design flaw. Nonetheless, the below code, as you requested in your comment, is changed to keep track of your UIImageViews in an array. Other than that, I left the code as you posted it. As a side-effect, this code also should solve the error you have been seeing.

```
var imageViews: [UIImageView] = []

func rotated(){

    self.imageScrollView.layoutIfNeeded()
    var iCount:CGFloat = 0
    var viewFrame = self.imageScrollView.frame
    var viewHeight = viewFrame.height
    var subviews:NSArray = self.imageScrollView.subviews
    for view in imageViews{
        var frame = CGRectMake(0, iCount * viewHeight, self.imageScrollView.frame.width, self.imageScrollView.frame.height)
        ++iCount
        view.frame = frame

    }
}
```

The code to initialize the UIImageViews (presumably in the same class, otherwise you have more work to do):

```
for image in self.gallery{
            var pImageView = UIImageView()
            pImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
            var frame = CGRectMake(0, iCount * viewHeight, self.imageScrollView.frame.width, self.imageScrollView.frame.height)
            ++iCount
            pImageView.frame = frame
            let file = image["pImage"] as? PFFile
            file?.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{(data: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                var tempData = data as! NSData
                pImageView.image = UIImage(data: tempData)
                self.imageScrollView.addSubview(pImageView)
                imageViews.append(pImageView)
            }
        }
```

All of a UIScrollView's subviews are UIViews (this is true for any UIView subclass: their subviews are all UIViews), but they are not necessarily all UIImageViews, and the ones that are UIImageViews are not necessarily the UIImageViews you added. There is no guarantee that UIScrollView does not contain views that you didn't add to it.

Comment: Works like a dream. Thank you. I didn't realise that putting them in an array kept a reference to them in the scrollview.